# PHP - Keep serial port open

Tags: php, serial-port, arduino, usb

Arduino requires a 2 second delay before you can send it any instructions through serial port. This is a problem when you are working with webpages, because you are adding 2 seconds to your loading time. How can I resolve this?
Is there a way to keep the serial port open, in way of 'remembering' the serial object using PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user574632 why then? How do I use AJAX for remembering an object?

Comment: You dont, you use ajax to call the slow php script, so the user sees a page instantly, and the processing happens in the background

Comment: @user574632 So.. it is not really possible to do this server side?

Comment: @rhbvkleef - yes, everything is done server side. It works like this: user loads page (no serial access done yet); browser makes AJAX request to server which starts serial access - server is now processing serial access script; some time later, browser makes another AJAX request for status update, or to send commands to serial; or whatever - at this point, the serial processing is still going on (that slow process that started earlier) but the browser is still able to communicate with the server.

Comment: No php does not have a built in way to handle persistent serial port connections (as far as im aware). You might be able to find an extension you install (if you can install software on the server) but 2 seconds isnt a huge amount of time IF he user is being kept updated, as the ajax approach does

Comment: Write a daemon that holds open the serial connection [preferably not in PHP], and then have your script talk to/through that daemon instead of directly opening the serial port.